# What is this collection of random travel encounters?

Tags: published-adventures, product-identification, d20-system

I was looking for ideas for random encounters for a party travelling with a caravan. I found several free online. During my search I also found a series (four or five volumes) of published supplements each containing roughly five detailed encounters tailored toward travel. As luck would have it I've run out of ideas for travel encounters, but my party is still travelling so now I want to find these supplements.

Here are some details that I remember from the *Amazon* description and reviews. There was one encounter where players were lured off the path by pixies and forced to join an enchanted dance. In another the travelers encounter a circus or carnival in which the attending guests kept disappearing.

I can't remember if these were for d20, *Pathfinder* or *D&D*, but I believe they were available as both print and ebooks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are thinking of the En Route series in the Atlas Games Penumbra/d20 3e-compatible line. There are three of them with about 20 encounters each.  The first, [En Route](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589780043), has the carnival and pixie dance you mention.  [En Route II: By Land Or By Sea](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158978037X) and [En Route III: The Road Less Traveled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589780523) are the sequels.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the exact one you are looking for, but it's free from Drive Thru RPG: [100 Roadside Encounter Ideas](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/112356/100-Roadside-Encounter-Ideas).

And the Forgotten Realms Book of Lairs was one of my favorite with lots of humorous encounters. $9.99 also on [Drive Thru](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/16846/Book-of-Lairs-Forgotten-Realms-2e?it=1).